umap.plot requires pandas matplotlib datashader bokeh holoviews scikit-image and colorcet to be installed
import sklearn.datasets
pendigits = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
mapper = umap.UMAP().fit(pendigits.data)
umap.plot.connectivity(mapper, show_points=True)

Above code gave me the error below.
umap.plot requires pandas matplotlib datashader bokeh holoviews scikit-image and colorcet to be installed

How to solve the error?

Self-answers are encouraged, but there's a certain way of doing them - you can read a little more about them in the Help Center.

@Andrew Yim Thank you for information.

Sorry, I should've been clearer. If you're going to self-answer a question, general practice is to post the question alone as the question, then post the answer/solution as an actual answer.

@Andrew Yim Thanks. I answered my question.

The solution is as below.
pip install umap-learn[plot]
import umap.umap_ as umap
import umap.plot
1st one will make a clear of error.

I upload self-answered question as nobody gave a solution in Stackoverflow.
Hope it helps you.

Use the below 2 commands
pip install holoviews
pip install datashader

Then import below libraries:
import pandas as pd
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf
import datashader.bundling as bd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import colorcet
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.cm
import bokeh.plotting as bpl
import bokeh.transform as btr
import holoviews as hv
import holoviews.operation.datashader as hd

And code will run fine
